# regex expression not working python

Tags: python

I have tried the following code in python, but it didn't seem to work properly. What should I change if I want to get the numbers from the st variable?

```
import re
reg = re.compile('[0-9][0-9]*[0-9]')
st = '[1560845405000000,8535474176'
m = reg.match(st)
print(m)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way to go, use `findall` instead of `match`:

```
import re

reg = re.compile(r'\d+')
st = '[1560845405000000,8535474176'
m = reg.findall(st)

print(m)
```

**Output:**

```
['1560845405000000', '8535474176']
```